# How to create a row that has 2 rows stacked next to it in html?

Tags: html, html-table

How can I achieve this table?

[basically a row that is has slightly higher height and 2 rows stacked together next to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbbCP.jpg)

Comment: I wrote a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g74dvjh8/9/) not using tables just in case you need it using Bootrstrap Grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowspan` when merge rows and you can also use `colspan` when merge columns. Give them a number that how much rows or columns will merge.

And here is the code

```
<table>
  <tr><td rowspan="2">test</td><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome. I will just wrap my head around this code but this is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!